# Dynamic default value for knitr chunks

Tags: r, knitr, default-value

Is there a way to do that ? Precisely, I know that it is possible to set up default values for knitr chunks with `opts_chunk$set(...)` but what if I want to have the same behaviour as in base R functions, ie defaulting let's say `param2` to `param1`:

```
<<chunkname,param1="sth">>=
# here I would like to have param2 = param1
# but I'll get param2 = opts_current$get("param2")
@

<<chunkname,param1="sth", param2="sth2">>=
# both parameters are specified, usual behaviour
@
```

**EDIT**

I tried a workaround with `knit_hook` but I couldn't get it work for graphical parameters `fig.width` and `fig.height`

```
   knit_hooks$set(dynamic.default = function(before, options, envir) {
        if (before) {
              if(is.null(opts_current$get("param2"))) opts_current$set(param2=opts_chunk$get("param1"))
        }}
   )

   opts_chunk$set(param2=NULL, dynamic.default=TRUE)
```

If I use `print(opts_current$get("param2"))` I do have the right value, but if I want to plot something, I got an error because of a `NULL` length in `options$fig.height`

**EDIT 2**

I also tried to put:

```
opts_chunk$set(fig.height=expression(opts_current$get("fig.width")))
```

but I got an error "non numeric argument for binary operator"